# CKEditor keeps giving undefined error

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I created a textarea on which I would like to initiate CKEditor. I also have a simple button that  when the user clicks on, the data from the CKEditor will be stored in a variable.

The problem is that I keep getting an undefined error:

```
TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.Textarea is undefined
[Break On This Error]   
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.Textarea.getData();
```

This has been driving me crazy for the last 3 hours and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div id='texteditor-container'>
<textarea id='texteditor-textarea' name='Textarea'></textarea>
</div>

//save button
<a class='texteditor-save-button' href='#'>Save</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//enables ckeditor on text area */
CKEDITOR.replace('Textarea'); 

// clicking save will send  data to database 
jQuery('.texteditor-save-button').click(function() {

//saves the content of the  editor 

var data = CKEDITOR.instances.Textarea.getData();
alert(data);    

return false;   

}); //end click
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps use the id of the textarea field instead of the name ('texteditor-textarea' as opposed to 'Textarea'?

Comment: Thank you so much spadelives! that did it!